# Scheduled task trigger for when GPO can't run on start (no DC)?

Tags: windows, boot, script, scheduled-tasks, group-policy

I am pushing a startup script via GPO.  The script updates a local script (in case of changes or deletion) and then runs itself.

I would like to have the local script run on startup ONLY if the machine is off-line and can't receive the updated script.  Is there an event log item for can't-reach-the-DC-to-apply-GPO-on-boot that I can trigger off of?  I don't want the script to run every time the DC is unavailable (e.g. temporary network disruption), only at boot when the DC is unavailable.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One fairly straightforward way would be to always run a PowerShell script at startup that then checks whether the domain is available:

```
Try {
    [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetComputerDomain() | Out-Null
} Catch {
    # Code here
}
```

If no domain controller can be contacted, the [`GetComputerDomain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.getcomputerdomain(v=vs.110).aspx) function throws an exception and execution falls into the catch block. If the domain is available, the function succeeds and the script is over.

Of course, the code in a PowerShell script needs to be PowerShell, but you can run classic batch by dumping a script to a temporary file, running the batch processor, and then deleting that file:

```
Try {
    [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetComputerDomain() | Out-Null
} Catch {
    $tmpBat = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() + '.bat'
    @"
rem                              PUT YOUR BATCH CODE HERE
"@ | Out-File $tmpBat -Encoding ASCII
    cmd /c $tmpBat
    Remove-Item $tmpBat
}
```

The lack of whitespace before the batch code is intentional; it's necessary for the multiline string literal (the thing delineated by `@"` and `"@`), which saves you from needing to deal with PowerShell escaping.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I think it will do what I need.  The script is powershell.  Running from GPO, it copies it's current version locally and updates a startup task.  Using your suggestion, if the domain is available AND it is running from the DC it does X.  If  the domain is not available, it also does X.  That should make it only do X once per boot.